# Getting JSON object from a URL

Tags: java, json

I'm writing an application using the public Tumblr API, just for fun. I have set up my oauth keys, and I have the URL for accessing my blog's info. I was wondering how I could take the JSON-encoded data from that page and turn it into Strings for working with.

To be clear, if I wanted a blog's title, I could send a request to this URL and select the data for the title.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) for retrieving JSON data from a rest service. Below is the sample

```
Representation entity = new ClientResource("your url").get();
JsonRepresentation jsonRepresentation = new JsonRepresentation(entity.getText());
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonRepresentation.getJsonObject();
```